ggsurvplot - adjust thickness of strata indicators
Is it possible to adjust the thickness of the strata indicators?
The indicators in the legend are not as thick as in the risk.table.
library(survminer)
library(survival)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

p <- ggsurvplot(
  fit,
  size = 1,
  legend.labs = c("A", "B"),
  linetype = "solid",
  break.time.by = 365,
  palette = c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF"),
  risk.table = TRUE,
  censor = FALSE,
  risk.table.title = "No. at risk",
  tables.y.text = FALSE,
  legend.title = "",
  tables.theme = theme_cleantable() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20))
)
p

The red arrow indicates the discrepancies in line thickness.

I tried to adjust but I am not aware how to find out which argument is related to the indicators. If there is one at all.
  tables.theme = theme_cleantable() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
          strata.line.x = element_line(size = 5.5))


Does this answer your question? ggplot with 2 y axes on each side and different scales

This is about a second y axis? My question is if there is a solution to adjust the thickness of the color indicators that they fit with the indicators in the legend.

tables.y.text = TRUE :-)

The text that appears in the risk table on the y-axis (tables.y.text) is TRUE by default. If you change this to FALSE, you'll get a thick line instead. This is achieved internally using element_markdown from the ggtext package. The actual function is .set_large_dash_as_ytext.
I agree that it is thicker than it should be. However, you can change it to use a thinner dash with the unicode value for a small em dash (\ufe58):
p$table <- p$table + 
  scale_y_discrete(labels=rep("\ufe58", 2)) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "cm")); p




link to list of unicode values
